# Why does my coefficients only have 1 dimension?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, naivebayes

I am trying to do an sentimental analysis on some review data. The response variable is 'positive' or 'negative'. I ran my model and my coefficients are only 1 dimension, I believe it should be two because of two response variables. Any help is appreciated to figure out why this is.

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import BernoulliNB
from sklearn import cross_validation
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
import textblob as TextBlob



#scikit
comments = list(['happy','sad','this is negative','this is positive', 'i like this', 'why do i hate this'])
classes = list(['positive','negative','negative','positive','positive','negative'])


# preprocess creates the term frequency matrix for the review data set
stop = stopwords.words('english')
count_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(analyzer =u'word',stop_words = stop, ngram_range=(1, 3))
comments = count_vectorizer.fit_transform(comments)
tfidf_comments = TfidfTransformer(use_idf=True).fit_transform(comments)


# preparing data for split validation. 60% training, 40% test
data_train,data_test,target_train,target_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(tfidf_comments,classes,test_size=0.2,random_state=43)
classifier = BernoulliNB().fit(data_train,target_train)

classifier.coef_.shape
```

The final line prints out (1L, 6L). I am trying to figure out the informative features for both negative and positive but since its 1L it will give me the same information for both response.

Thank you!

Comment: Actually the last line printed (2, 6) for me. Are you sure its (1, 6)?

Comment: There's a typo with test_size, it should be "0.2", can you try it again with that?

Answer (score 0):

In the [source code for scikit learn preprocessing module](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/c957249/sklearn/preprocessing/label.py#L172), the LabelBinarizer class implements the one-vs-all scheme for multi-label classification. You can see therein that if only two classes are present, it learns one set of coefficients which predict if a sample is of class "1", and if not, the classifier predicts "0".